# Filter a JTable with Hidden Data through a JComboBox

Tags: filter, jtable, jcombobox, tablerowsorter

I want to filter a JTable with a JComboBox. I found a Method to do this, the TableRowSorter but it sorts the table with the Rows. In my case the JTabel has just one column "ArticleName" which shows a specific data from an ArrayList (Category, ArticleNr, ArticleName, Price, Details). To be specific it just shows the ArticleName but if you click on an item in the Jtable it will load the data into JTextfields so you can see all the information.

This is code sample of the FilterMethod:

```
private void filter(String query) {
    TableRowSorter<ArticleTModel> tr= new TableRowSorter<ArticleTModel>(tmArticle);
    tblArticle.setRowSorter(tr);

    if (query != "Alle") {
        tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(query));
    }
    else {
        tblArticle.setRowSorter(tr);
    }
}
```

I have an `Article` class with the getter & setters and an own TableModel which is the ArticleTModel / tmArticle

Comment: I tried to add the Column "Category" to the Table and now the filtering works but from my Design its not enough Space for both Categorys, but now there is another Problem... Like i wrote if i click on a Row it gives the whole Information about an Article to JTextFields but now if i filter the Data and click then on the row it always gives me the Data from the first Articel as if i didnt't filter the Table

Comment: By the Way im pretty far with my Project of a virtual Store ... You can login as a Admin where u can create, edit,delete and view Articles,Customers, Workers and cancel Orders or allow them and u can login as a ServiceWorker who can create and view Customers and only can view Articles and Workers also the service worker can place orders. If u like to see the whole Code i can post it :D but there are about 26 Clases :P